# google drive apps script > "Service unavailable: Docs"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a script that takes a Google spreadsheet writes the text to a Google Doc.  When I try to run the function, I get the message in red at the top of the page `Service unavailable: Docs (Dismiss)`.  This is new.  What does this error mean?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when appending a paragraph element to a document, if the paragraph element contains an image. I think it's related to either of the following bugs:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142533361

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117212337

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Pierre-Marie Richard's answer, the error [`Service unavailable: Docs`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/SR1fCKkl24o/HuZwg1nNaxwJ) usually happens when you are using an invalid Doc ID.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#common_errors) :

> **Server not available.**
>   **Server error occurred, please try again.**
>   There are a couple possible causes for this error:
>
> - A Google server or system is temporarily unavailable. Wait for a few moments and try running the script again.
> - There is an error in your script that doesn't have a corresponding error message. Try debugging your script and see if you can isolate the problem.
> - There is a bug in Google Apps Script that is causing this error. Report the error on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).