# google script service Docs ligne 19 when calling openById(docIDs[i])

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to merge all the files in only one document so I tried this fonction and I have an error  >>> Service indisponible : Docs (ligne 19, in "Code" file. How can I solve it ? Thank you very much :)

```
function mergeGoogleDocs() {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Pd-7GIdm9-PdevjSUr4ZCkYEzSPYWT8U'); // set folder ID were we should look for files to merge
  var docIDs = [];
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    docIDs.push(file.getId());
  }

  Logger.log(docIDs); // check if we have some ids

  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById('1G0MPkr5AbgkPpUT6uG5WoJ7RKkIkP_tDWzzns31Q6bU'); // set document id of doc which will contain all merged documents
  baseDoc.getBody().clear(); // clear the whole document and start with empty page
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for (var i = 1; i < docIDs.length; ++i ) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getActiveSection();    
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        body.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        body.appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("Unknown element type: "+type);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit :   In fact it was my error that I haven't checked before that in the folder I had a Spreadsheet so I have to verify the type of the document MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS thank you tehhowch ^^^and with the code below I don't have the error anymore but the final file is empty.In fact with view logs i have the id of the final merged file only (which is blank) .So if you have an idea :)

```
var types = [MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS];
  for (var t in types) {
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Pd-7GIdm9-PdevjSUr4ZCkYEzSPYWT8U').getFilesByType(types[t]);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      docIDs.push(file.getId());
      Logger.log('File id  ' + file.getId()); 
    }
  }
```

The final edit: The code works!The reason the file was empty it was because I've uploaded word documents from my computer and not Google Docs. :)

Comment: View -> Logs or View -> Execution Transcription should give you a little more information. Are you able to add logs and give us more information as to where could be erroring? It could be the Else getting hit.

Comment: In View -> Logs I have a very long error message I just copied the firest part It's that : [18-06-11 14:35:24:705 CEST] [1gs6nqiCbumdj8zJ03EmZUwaRATiije_jekEfnH1L5vPiXB8fz_SH0Rdh, 1G0MPkr5AbgkPpUT6uG5WoJ7RKkIkP_tDWzzns31Q6bU, 1Tz5RtT3MsUevj_1o2LB17WSn69sSsN4h, 1Puch4F_czL-CtkFyxV2QwPTVUaV95NSO, 1ls-cR0iR48CSrlh-wE0MNnricHN16ALT,

Comment: So I've added the logs and I am in the good file and my destination merged Google doc is right >> Logger.log('Folder name  ' + folder.getName()); and Logger.log('Merged file(destination)  ' + baseDoc.getName());

Comment: You are trying to open a file that is not a Google Docs file, with the Google Docs service. **Of course** this cannot work. Instead of blindly assuming that a file is of `MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS`, actually check that first. Or better, use `Folder#searchFiles` to specify what type you work with.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50475578/9337071 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44880981/9337071 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44653721/9337071

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive apps script > "Service unavailable: Docs"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653721/google-drive-apps-script-service-unavailable-docs)

Comment: Yes!Because I have a spreadsheet in the same folder this is why!You save my life. As you said I have to be sure that the file is a Google doc so by doing  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS); it still doesn't work :( By doing this I don't have the error anymore but the merged file is not completed(white as the snow)^^^^

Comment: In fact with view logs i have the id of the final merged file only (which is blank)